# Is there any function that is convex after compounded with a squared loss (besides linear ones)?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, loss-functions, convex

It is known that a linear function compounded with a squared loss is convex, so one can efficiently find the optimal solution when performing linear regression. Specifically, given a data point $(x,y)$ we have the loss function
$$f(w)=(w^Tx-y)^2,$$
which is convex in $w$. I'm wondering if there exist other functions that satisfy this condition. And is it possible or meaningful to design new learning algorithms with such functions?

Thanks in advance.